# Job research with pending degree validation

Tags: job-search, france, degree, apprentice

I am currently finishing a masters degree, but I know that my college is *extremely* slow for diploma validation. Between one or two months between the end of the year and the  deliberation, after wich it takes weeks to get a paper saying you got the degree.

While I am fairly certain that by the end of the school year I can be about 90% sure of the result of the degree, can that absence of proof for the degree be an issue for job seeking?

Should I wait for said degree to be validated to start searching for work?

Edit: as for the timeframe, i am finishing the degree the 31st of august, they deliberate end of september and result are given at the latest mid october.

it is a master degree as a part time apprentice

Comment: When will you finish school?  In May of 2023?  When will you receive the paper diploma degree?  In July?

Comment: What does "90% sure of the result of the degree" mean?

Comment: I tried to fix the spelling in your post to the best of my ability. Since you said you get a "master" degree, I removed the "apprentice" tag. If I got that wrong, please correct it.

Comment: @toolic in france, with aprentership, the end of the school year is the 31st of august, and they would deliberate at the very end of september, with result given at the latest mid october

Comment: @nvoigt thanks for the edit, but i will put the aprentice tag back on as i am doing my master degree as an aprentice, and i prefere to keep the tag on if that is relevent.

Comment: Edit all this information into the question, rather than here in the comments.

Comment: Done.

also, what i mean by 90% sure is that i can make an educated guess on will i get the degree or not.

Comment: Okay, I admit I am confused... are you getting a masters degree (so a MSc from a university) or are you finishing an apprenticeship? Or is this a special thing that gets you both?

Comment: in france you can be an apprentice at any level of your degree. it is pretty common nowaday to have your last year being an aprentership to not pay for school tuition. the time you spend in your company is graded is considered as a course too 

but it is still a fully proper and recognized master degree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I wait for said degree to be validated to start searching for work?

You should search for jobs now.

You should also update your resume to indicate that you are **expected** to get your degree in October 2023.

For example, you can add the following info to your resume:

```
University ABCD
MS in Computer Science (Expected October 2023).
```

Then, during the job interviews, you can explain in more details to the recruiters or hiring managers to make sure that everything is transparent.

Comment: Agree. In my case it took more time as I had to wait for the physical paper to be *mailed* to me (I was doing an oversea degree online) which took 4 weeks. Simply state that on your resume and start job search.

Answer (score 1):

In general the school will reply correctly to inquiries from companies even if the paper hasn't yet been printed.

If the concern is that the school may answer more accurately than you would prefer: Employers are very used to handling applications from students who are in "candidate for degree" status rather than technically having been granted the degree. They're going to look at the transcript anyway; if you have decent grades they'll see that. I have many friends who were hired before getting their sheepskin, had a hang-up of some sort and never technically graduated (*), and it wasn't a problem since they were already demonstrating that they had the skills. And once you have a few years of real experience, an incomplete degree really makes no difference; again, it's a matter of whether you can do the job, not how you learned to do so.

I wouldn't worry about it.

(*: *ABD*: All But Degree)

Comment: "*While I am fairly certain that by the end of the school year I can be about 90% sure of the result of the degree, can that absence of proof for the degree be an issue for job seeking?*" -> to what you answer that they will reply correctly -> the school will ***not*** reply correctly to inquiries if the student hasn't successfully validated his year/diploma, which seems to be the case at this time

Comment: Or more accurately, the school will reply more correctly than the student might want? Realistically that may not be an issue either; I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would start sending out applications, I wouldn't say I have a Masters degree, but I would put something like 'pending' or put an explanation in my Cover letter that you've completed all the course work and waiting on validation.

Key point is not to lie that you have a validated degree, but there's nothing to stop you from applying - if they do a phone interview - you can discuss this point - perhaps talk about what sort of marks you were getting for course work (e.g. if you were nailing all the other aspects of your degree and give them the impression that the validation is a mere formality at this stage) - and if they absolutely need a degree - then you can give them time frames - they may be okay to wait, they may not - they may talk with the University, they may not.

I would apply and then see how far I get.